# When deleting a post that has the auto-generated "controversial review task" show delete votes

Tags: feature-request, review, moderator-tools

I recently deleted a post that was downvoted and received a "controversial review" flag.

However, it only shows my delete vote - it would be really nice if instead of showing it as a unilateral moderator delete, the votes from those who recommended deletion also appeared as they do when the post is fully deleted by the review queue.